# Architecture neural network OCR for Printed Documents

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow, ocr, conv-neural-network

I'm learning neural network by using tensorflow to build a OCR for printed documents.

Would you mind giving me advices which Architecture neural network is good for recognize characters. 
I'm confusing because I'm a newbie and there are a lot of neural network designs

I found [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) CLASSIFIER but their architectures are only about digit. 
I don't know their architectures can work with characters or not ?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you correctly point out, recognizing documents is a different thing from recognizing single characters. It is a complex system that will take time to implement from scratch. First, there is the problem of preprocessing. You need to find where the text is, perhaps slightly rotate it, etc. That can be done with heuristics and a library like [OpenCV](http://www.opencv.org). You'll also have to detect things like page numbers, header/footers, tables/figures, etc.

Then, in some cases, you could take the "easy" route and use heuristics to segment the text into characters. That works for block characters, but not cursive scripts.

If the segmentation is given, and you don't have to guess it, you have to solve multiple related problems, each are like MNIST but they are related in that the decisions are not independent. You can look up [MEMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum-entropy_Markov_model) (Maximum-Entropy Markov Models) vs HMM ([Hidden Markov Models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model), [Hidden Conditional Random Fields](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/training-algorithms-for-hidden-conditional-random-fields/), and [Segmental Conditional Random Fields](http://www.clsp.jhu.edu/workshops/10-workshop/speech-recognition-with-segmental-conditional-random-fields/), and study the difference between them. You can also read about [seq2seq](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/seq2seq.py).

So if you're making it simple for yourself, you can essentially run MNIST classifiers multiple times, once the segmentation is revealed (via some heuristic in opencv). On top of that, you have to run a [dynamic program](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/27aa/beba3b8c10ee9326ecfbe9b6d1b37d7ebb02.pdf) which finds the best final sequence based on the score of each decision, and a "language model", which assigns likelihoods of letters occurring close to each other.

If you're starting from scratch, it's not an easy thing. It may take months for you to get a basic understanding. Happy hacking!

Comment: Thank you for your advice.

My goal is use Neural network and recognize each letter (eg: a,b...x,y,z, A,B..).

Now,I can segment each letter from the picture and I learn tensorflow by running example from this tutorial https://github.com/nlintz/TensorFlow-Tutorials and reading this book http://www.deeplearningbook.org/ So what I confusing now is how to find a good model or architecture for tensorflow to recognize. Thank you

Comment: You can use the same MNIST classifier for letters. There is nothing inherent in the architecture that is digit-only.

Comment: Thank you, then I will choose the lowest error rate classifier. 
And about the training data set letters. I print then scan this file https://github.com/shaolinkhoa/tensorflow/blob/master/print.pdf 
Then I segment each letter in those scaned pictures so that I will have a lot of training data pictures for each letter.Is my solution correctly ?

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable approach.

Comment: Thank you for your kind support, I will research and update the situation later.

Comment: I tried to build with many Neural Network models but it recognized wrong.

+ I used character's pictures (32x24) which are segmented from scanned document to trainning.
ndimage.imread(image_file).astype(float)

+ scaled values: [0.0, 255.0] => [-1.0, 1.0] by
image_data = (image_data - 255.0 / 2) / (255.0 / 2)

+ then fed in tensorflow models which had 5 hidden layers:
900 - 1500 - 900 - 600 - 300
or 1000 - 1500 - 900 - 700 - 100 
... etc

I changed the number of hidden neurons and the numbers hidden layers. But It still recognize wrong.
Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: What error rate do you get on the train set? Does the objective function decrease and converge?

Comment: My input and output ( 768 - 36). If I use more than 3 hidden layers and more than 1000 neurons in each hidden layers ( follow the classifier in MNIST), the error rate is very high ( ~25%) . But if I use 2 hidden layers ( 1000 - 500 ), the error rate is lower (~5%) but result is wrong too. I'm really confused.

Comment: Can you feed a training example to test? Definitely the 2 hidden layers is the better choice. If the training examples are fine, but unseen ones aren't, then try increasing the dropout rate and/or making the model smaller.